# Transferring a string from AWS Lambda to an EC2 instance that is started in the same lambda function

Tags: input, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, instance, transfer

I am completely new to working with AWS. Currently I am in the following situation: My lambda function starts an EC2 instance. This instance will need the information contained in the 'ID' variable. I was wondering how I could transfer this data from my lambda function to the EC2 instance. Is this even possible?

```
import boto3

region = 'eu-west-1'
instances = ['AnEC2Instance-ID']
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    ID = event.get('ID')
    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print('started your instance: ' + str(instances))
```

Here 'AnEC2Instance-ID' is supposed to be an EC2 instance ID.
This lambda function is triggered by a gateway API. The ID is obtained from this Gatway API using the line: ID = event.get('ID')

Answer (score 0):

These EC2 instances have already been launched and in this lambda are being started via boto3 `ec2.start_instances`.  Prior to this you would have to do some clever AWS stuff to modify the instance's `user-data` and also have the instance configured to re-run the `user-data` at start (not just launch).  Quite complex IMHO.

Two alternate suggestions:

- Revisit your need to start an existing EC2 instance, as you can easily pass data to a new instance with boto3 in the `client.run_instances` function.
- Or if you truly need to revive an existing EC2 instance, you might need a third component to manage the correlation of EC2 instance IDs and your Event IDs: how about DynamoDB?  First your script above writes a key-value pair of the InstanceID and Event ID.  Then invoke `ec2.start_instances` and when the EC2 instance starts it is pre-configured [to do](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`, and uses that value to query the DynamoDB?

Answer (score 0):

When launch an Amazon EC2 instance, you can provide data in the **User Data** parameter.

This data will then be accessible on the instance via:

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data/
```

This technique is also used to pass a **startup script** to an instance. There is software provided on the standard Amazon AMIs that will run the script if it starts with specific identifiers. However, you can simply pass any data via **User Data** to make it available to the instance.